# How to save files correctly in a data folder

Tags: python

Lets say I have created a dataframe and want to save it as a csv file in a data folder.

I do it the following way.

```
path = os.getcwd()
path_to_data = os.path.join(path, 'data')
df.to_csv(os.path.join(path_to_data, 'coordinates_speed.csv'))
```

My teacher told me as far as I remember:

1. It is wrong to assume there will be a folder named data
2. You should use an absolute path

Could someone tell me how to do it the correct way?

Comment: First, check whether a folder with that name exists in the current directory. This can be done in 2 ways - via python libraries or a cmdline command within `os.subprocess`. Check python documentation for how to get the absolute path of the current dir, and apply that to the file creation.

Comment: Hint for 1: If there is no such a folder, you could create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the data folder exist and if not to make the folder named data, so this way you wont assume that the data folder might not be created.

```
import os

if os.path.exists('data'):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir('data')

df.to_csv('data/coordinates_speed.csv')
```

Comment: Alternatively use `os.makedirs('data', exist_ok=True)` to get rid of the if else statement.

Comment: Didn't know that was possible, that would make the code cleaner for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Super quick `pathlib` solution

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path

# append to current working directory
>>> folder = Path('.') / 'data'

# create folder if it doesn't exist
>>> folder.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# save df
>>> df.to_csv(folder / 'coordinates_speed.csv')
```